# google-cliend-loader ignores apiRoot and appId

Tags: google-app-engine, polymer, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to use in my polymer app API from Google Cloud Endpoints.
I have my API loaded into Google App Engine and can explore it via Explorer - everything is ok here.

As well - I can use other standard Google API (like plus) via google-cliend-loader:

```
<google-client-loader id="plus" name="plus" version="v1"
  on-google-api-load="plusLoaded">
</google-client-loader>
```

everything working fine.

BUT - then I try to use my API:

```
<google-client-loader appId="my-application-id" name="myApi" version="v1"
  on-google-api-load="backendLoaded">
</google-client-loader>
```

I still see in console:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/myApi/v1/rest?fields=kind%…%2Cversion%2CrootUrl%2CservicePath%2Cresources%2Cparameters%2Cmethods&pp=0 404 ()
```

So - it looks like it is trying to get API from Google - not from my application.

Anything missed on my side? Are there any working example of using  and Endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Polymer docs on [property binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#property-binding):

> To bind to camel-case properties of elements, use dash-case in the attribute name. For example:
>
> ```
> <user-view first-name="{{managerName}}"></user-view>
> <!-- Sets <user-view>.firstName = this.managerName; -->
> ```

To declaratively set the `appId` property, you would use:

```
<google-client-loader app-id="my-application-id" ...>
```